# What is the probability of rolling X specific numbers on Y six-sided dice?

Tags: probability, dice, binomial-distribution

I am writing the AI for a dice game and I have hit a mental block.

I need to know the probability of rolling $X$ specific numbers on Y six-sided dice, where $Y \leq 6$ and $X < Y$ (otherwise the probability would obviously be 0!)

E.g. What is the probability of rolling a 2 and a 4 with 5 dice.

I know that the number of total rolls is $6^Y$ so the answer must be something like...

$f(x,y)/(6^Y)$

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suggestion 1: use mathjax or the system will eat anything after $<$.

Comment: Would it be possible to clarify "X specific numbers"? Do you mean the probability of rolling a 2 or a 4 on one roll, rolling a 2 and then a 4 on two consecutive rolls, or rolling at least one 2 and at least one 4 over several rolls?

Comment: Sure! In the above example, you roll five dice all at the same time, and you need a 2 and a 4 (at least one of each).

Comment: Are the numbers always distinct? That is, do you care about rolling at least two 2s and a 3, for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of rolling at least one from $X$ specified numbers when *given* $Y$ rolls of a cubic die is the probability of *not* rolling *none* of them.

$$f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) ~=~ 1-\left(\frac{6-x}{6}\right)^y\qquad\Big[x\in \Bbb N,y\in \Bbb N,1\leq x\leq \min\{y, 6\}\Big]$$

The probability of rolling $X$ specific number at least once each, when given $Y$ rolls of a cubic die is, the probability of *not* missing *any* of them.

$$g_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) ~=~ 1-\sum_{k=0}^x \binom 6{x-k}(-1)^k \left(\frac{6-x+k}{6}\right)^y\qquad\Big[x\in \Bbb N,y\in \Bbb N,1\leq x\leq \min\{y, 6\}\Big]$$

Comment: Cool! My sigma notation is a little rusty, but this could work! Apologies for being dumb, but with the sigma notation, I basically add up all the values of that formula where K starts at 0 and ends at X?

Comment: Ah... I have another dumb question: the notation just after the sigma... it's not 6 divided by (x-k) is it? Because that would give me a divide by zero. I am assuming I have just read it wrong! Thanks for your help - this is awesome! :D

Comment: Binomial coefficient.  $\binom n r= \frac{n!}{r!~(n-r)!}$ $$\dbinom 6{x-k} = \dfrac{6!}{(x-k)!(6-x+k)!}$$

Comment: Yep - just realised... I will plug this into my AI and see how it does - thanks very much! :D

Comment: OK... I think I must have misunderstood something. I plugged  x= 2 and y = 2 into that formula as a test and got a result of -2.5 when I was expecting 1/36. Am I missing something? Sorry for being a bit slow! :(

Answer (score 2):

If you roll $5$ six-sided dice, there are $5^5$ ways not to roll a two, $5^5$ ways not to roll a four, and $4^5$ ways to roll neither a two nor a four.  By inclusion-exclusion, the number of obtaining at least one two and at least one four when rolling $5$ dice is

$$6^5-5^5-5^5+4^5$$

Comment: Thanks... I am not sure I follow you though. The player needs to score both a 2 and a 4. so should the number be...

$6^5 - 5^5 - 5^5 - 4^5$

?

Comment: Its the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.  The count of any result, minus the counts of missing at least one required number, plus the count of missing both.

Comment: Ah... I see.  Does this scale up? For example, what if I needed to roll three 3s with 6 dice?

Comment: Not so easily.  The probability of rolling *exactly* three 3s with six die is: $$\binom 63 \frac{1^35^3}{6^6}$$ The probability of rolling *at least* three 3s is $$\binom 63 \frac{1^3 5^3}{6^6}+\binom 64 \frac{1^4 5^2}{6^6}+\binom 65 \frac{1^5 5^1}{6^6}+\frac{1^6 5^0}{6^6}$$

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your setup, you are rolling $Y$ dice, each with $n$ numbered sides, and wish to calculate the probability of getting a set of $X$ distinct numbers at least once each.

$$\{a_1,a_2,...,a_X\},\ X\le\min(n,Y)$$

In order to calculate the probability, we need to count the number of rolls that satisfy this condition. It is actually more convenient to consider the rolls that do not.

The number of rolls in which $a_1$ does not appear at all is $(n-1)^Y$, and likewise for all the other values. We then simply need to compute the number for which at least one of these numbers does not appear, which is to say, which is to say, the union of the set of rolls for which one $a_i$ does not appear. This calls for the use of the [Inclusion Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

To obtain the cardinality of the union, we simply take the sum of the cardinalities of each individual set, minus the sum of the cardinalities of the intersections of all the pairs of sets, plus the cardinalities of the intersections of all groups of 3 sets, and so on. If we assume the numbers are distinct, the intersection of $m$ sets has cardinality $(n-m)^Y$, since it is the number of rolls in which neither of 2 distinct numbers appear. Also there are $\binom Xm$ possible groupings of $m$ sets. combining these and applying Inclusion-Exclusion, we obtain the number of rolls for which at least one $a_i$ does not appear:

$$(n-1)^Y-\binom X2(n-2)^Y+\binom X3(n-3)^Y+...=\sum_{i=1}^{X}(-1)^{i+1}\binom Xi(n-i)^Y$$

To obtain the number of rolls that do meet the criteria, we simply subtract this value from $n^Y$, the total number of rolls, yielding a compact result.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{X}(-1)^{i}\binom Xi(n-i)^Y$$

Since each individual roll is equally likely, the probability is just this value divided by the total number of rolls:

$$p=\frac 1{n^Y}\sum_{i=0}^{X}(-1)^{i}\binom Xi(n-i)^Y$$

Comment: Hmmm. This formula seems to give a correct result when tested with simple vlaues. Nice! :D